# Probability Poisson process yields even number after time $t$

Tags: probability, poisson-process

When you turn on your computer, a certain bit (0/1) is initialized to the value 0.

Suppose that starting from when the computer is turned on, the bit is incremented (adding 1 mod 2) at random times, on average λ
 times per millisecond. What is the probability that after 
 milliseconds the bit stores the value 0?

I know's I'm essentially seeking the probability a Poisson process returns even number after time $t$ given λ
 times per millisecond, but I'm not sure how to get the answer.

Comment: Just sum over all even $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2n}e^{-\lambda}}{(2n)!}= e^{-\lambda} \cosh \lambda$$

Comment: Basically you have $N_t$ is the number of increments in time $t$ milliseconds, and adding $1$ together $N_t$ many times just gives $N_t$, but then you wish to take this modulo $2$. So all in all your RV is $X_t=N_t \mod 2$. Clearly since we start at $0$ and start adding $1$’s, we see that $X_t=0$ if and only if $N_t$ is even. Thus $P(X_t=0)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(N_t=2k)$. How does this sound?

Comment: The series sums to $\frac{1}{2}(1 + e^{-2\lambda})$.

Comment: So the final answer has no time dependence? The answer after t milliseconds is just $.5(1+e^{-2 \lambda})$?

Comment: @theta no, I think one should replace $\lambda$ by $\lambda t$ in the computed expressions that are given in the other two comments. You can see explicitly, in one comment, they used the PMF for $Pois(\lambda)$ rather than $Pois(\lambda t)$.

Comment: It should be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(N_t=2k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \frac12\left(1+e^{-2\lambda t}\right).
$$
Note that in particular, $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac12\left(1+e^{-2\lambda t}\right) = \frac12$ as one would expect.